# Does further queryset manipulations change original queryset

Tags: python, django, logic, django-queryset

If we have a queryset say

```
eventset=Event.objects.filter(eventdate=date)
```

And later if I do something like this with the queryset object,would it be correct logic or will the eventset be manipulated?

```
for event in eventset.order_by('-likes'):
    if event.venue in venuerankings:
        venuerankings.append[event.venue]
```

Does the above part of code change the order of objects in 'eventset'?

Relevant part of the code.

```
totalvenues=len(Venues.objects.all()))
    events=[[''] * totalvenues for row in range(24)]
eventset=Event.objects.filter(eventdate=date)
venuerankings=[]
for event in eventset.order_by('-likes'):
    if event.venue in venuerankings:
        venuerankings.append[event.venue]
for venueno,venue in enumerate(venuerankings):
    for event in eventset.filter[venue=venue]:
        events[event.time][venueno]=event
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but isn't there something wrong with your syntax? I think you meant `venueranking.append(event.venue)`. Also, what are you trying to achieve here? What do you want `events` to be? An example of inputs and outputs would be very helpful.

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted, seems a reasonable question to me.  My understanding is eventset CAN be changed like this eventset = eventset.order_by('-likes') but just using it like you have will not effect it.

Comment: this is wat i am trying to do  with that code
http://dpaste.com/702412/
I havent yet completed other parts of the code so, I couldnt  post ant i/ps and o/ps. Please let me know if you find any incorrect logic that code.

Comment: @KamalReddy: It's time for you to accept some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not affect the original queryset, because querysets are lazy.

This means that in your loop `for event in eventset.order_by('-likes'):` you are doing two things:

(1) creating a new queryset ordered by '-likes'; and

(2) creating, in turn, each object specified by the queryset.

Accordingly, if you run the loop a second time, you will receive fresh objects, which will not reflect any unsaved changes made to the objects in the previous loop.